# Prove that $\{v_kv^\dagger_l\}$ are linearly independent if $A=\sum_k \lambda_kv_k v^\dagger_k$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, positive-definite, outer-product

> The spectral decomposition of a positive definite matrix $A=\sum_k \lambda_kv_k v^\dagger_k$ where $\lambda_k>0$ and $v_k$ are orthonormal vectors. How do we prove that the set $\{v_kv^\dagger_l\}$ are linearly independent.

If $A$ is $n\times n$ then there are $n$ linearly independent and orthonormal eigenvectors $v_k$. There $n\times n$ members in the set $\{v_kv^\dagger_l\}$ and there must be $n\times n$ members in the basis of the matrix space.

i.e., We have to prove that the set $\{v_kv^\dagger_l\}$ form a basis for the $n\times n$ matrix space.

**Note:** I am not asking to prove this by stating,

$\sum_{kl} c_{kl}v_kv^\dagger_l=0$ iff $c_{kl}=0$ for all $k,l$.

**Original Context**

[image: 11]
___________________________________________________________________
[image: 22]
___________________________________________________________________

[image: 33]

**My Attempt**

**[Theorem 1 :](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/linear-independence-properties-of-tensor-products-of-normed)** If $v_k$ and $w_k$ are basis of the vectorspaces $V$ and $W$ respectively, then $v_i\otimes w_j$ is a basis of the vectorspace $V\otimes W$.

where $\otimes$ respresent a tensor product between vectors.

In the case of column vectors $(v_i\otimes_{outer}w_j)$ the tensor product can be seen as a form of flattening of the outer product, i.e., there is a one-to-one correspondence between the vectorspaces $V\otimes W$ and $V\otimes_{outer} W$.

i.e., $V\otimes W$ is isomorphic to $V\otimes_{outer} W\implies V\otimes W\cong V\otimes_{outer} W$

**Theorem 2 :** If there is an isomorphism $T:V\to W$. The vectors $\{v_i\}$ form a basis  for $V$ iff $T(v_i)$ form a basis for $W$.

$v_i\otimes w_j$ form a basis for the vectorspace $V\otimes W$, from theorem, $v_i\otimes_{outer} w_j$ form a basis for the vectorspace $V\otimes_{outer} W$.

i.e., $v_i\otimes_{outer} w_j$ are linearly independent

Comment: why not solve this in the special case when all the $v_i$ are standard basis vectors?  Then for the general case use a similarity transform with $V$ to map your collection to that of standard basis vectors

Comment: I'm a little confused. You want to show $\{v_k v_l^\dagger\}$ is linearly independent, but you don't want to apply the definition of linear independence?

Comment: @TheoBendit In the underlined portion of the reference that I have attached, it says since $|\tilde{k}\rangle\langle\tilde{l}|$ are linearly independent, then the definition is true.

Comment: @user8675309 I have edited OP to include my attempt to a possible proof of the statement. Could you please help.

Comment: @TheoBendit I have edited OP. Could you please comment on my attempt ?

Comment: Your original post is a very simple statement with a very simple proof.  Do you really think introducing tensor products and a lot of other notation and machinery is helpful?  I stand by what I said with doing the simple case first involving standard basis vectors.